# Variably named variables in objective c++

Tags: objective-c++

Is it possible to do something along the lines of :

```
 Entity [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entitiy%i",entitiesCreated];
```

to create a variable called Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, Entityn?
I dont care how i go about doing it, i just need something that resembles variably named variables. They will be added to an array, if thats of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not "variables" as such, but the typical way to store data by name is via an associative data structure, such as `NSMutableDictionary` (in ObjC) or `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` (in C++). Have you investigated those? In particular, for example this approximates what you seem to be trying do:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
[dict addObject:somevalue forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entity%i",entitiesCreated]];
```

and then, to access values:

```
id val = [dict valueForKey:@"Entity1"];
```

or so.

I assume you're coming from another programming language such as JavaScript or PHP where such associative data structures are used for holding *all* variables - this is not the case in C-derived languages, where variables are statically allocated. You have to explicitly create any dynamic data structures.

Comment: Actually i come from BASH, where you can name variables from other variables, but thank you anyway... Would an array with the objects created as tmpObject then added to the array work?
Kinda like : (tmpObject create stuff)
tmpObject addtoarray stuff

Then could i access they object if i know its index?

Comment: @DuskFall If I understand you correctly, you're after `NSArray`/ `NSMutableArray` - any objects placed in one of those can be looked up by index using the `objectAtIndex:` method, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now seeing as i'm still new, how to i mark you up and close the question?